# Stability and Boundedness of Solutions of LTV system

Tags: dynamical-systems, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

I have the differential equation:
$$\dot{x} = \Phi(x,t)[Ax+f(t)] $$
where:
$$A \in R^{n\times n}- \ Hurwitz $$  $$ f(t) \in R^n \ and \ \Vert{f(t)\Vert < \infty}; $$
and $$ \Phi(x,t) = diag\{\frac{(e^{x_i}+1)^2}{e^{x_i}}\beta_i,\ \beta_i >0 ,\ i = 1..n\}=\begin{vmatrix}\frac{(e^{x_1}+1)^2}{e^{x_1}}\beta_1 & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots &\frac{(e^{x_i}+1)^2}{e^{x_i}}\beta_i & \vdots \\ 0& \cdots & \frac{(e^{x_n}+1)^2}{e^{x_n}}\beta_n \\\end{vmatrix}$$
My question: How do i  check if the solution of the equation is bounded and stable?
Thank you!

Comment: This question lacks context. What have you tried? Where is this problem from?

Comment: I want to check if the solution of the given system x(t) is stable? If stable, how to prove it? How to find the lyapunov function? Sorry for my English!

Comment: What do you mean by "stable" here? Probably you are interested in the autonomous system for $f(t)\equiv 0$? Then you can study the stability properties of the origin, which is the only equilibrium. Or do you want to show that for all bounded $f$, the state is also bounded, the BIBO stability? Note also that $\Phi(x,t)$ is actually $\Phi(x)$.